Excel sum of multiple arrays
I have 2 tables (can be 100x100 table) in excel in the following sample format:
Table 1) shows consumption amount of certain food at certain age category

Table 2) Number of persons at certain age category

I want to find amount of each food type required each year based on number of persons without creating additional tables:

It is multiplication and summing array problem, but could not find solution for this problem using sum, sumproduct, or sumifs.. Does it exist?
The result should look like this:


I figured out, I can  also use SUMIFS and TRANSPOSE functions in array to solve this; now got to run after work, will check and post tomorrow...

@ulviii  Can you share your solution with SUMIFS and TRANSPOSE?

Seems like MMULT with SUMIFS should do it:
=MMULT(SUMIFS(C2:C6,A2:A6,TOROW(A12:A14),B2:B6,A18:A20),--B12:D14)



Here is one way of doing this using the LAMBDA() helper function called MAKEARRAY()


• Formula used in cell K2
=MAKEARRAY(ROWS(J2:J4),COLUMNS(K1:M1),LAMBDA(r,c,
  LET(a, CHOOSECOLS(FILTER(A2:C6,INDEX(J2:J4,r)=B2:B6),1,3),
  SUM(FILTER(CHOOSEROWS(F2:H4,XMATCH(TAKE(a,,1), E2:E4)),INDEX(K1:M1,c)=F1:H1)*TAKE(a,,-1)))))


Also using REDUCE()+BYCOL() can return the whole array as output:


=REDUCE(HSTACK("",F1:H1),UNIQUE(B2:B6),LAMBDA(α,δ,
  LET(φ,FILTER(A2:C6,B2:B6=δ),VSTACK(α,HSTACK(δ,
  BYCOL(TAKE(φ,,-1)*CHOOSEROWS(F2:H4,--RIGHT(TAKE(φ,,1))),LAMBDA(Σ,SUM(Σ))))))))


NOTE: The above formula is one single dynamic array formula therefore one doesn't needs to fill right or fill down, it will spill for the whole array, also the functions exclusively works with MS365 and you will need to change the cell references/ranges as per your suit.


Another LAMBDA and MAKEARRAY suggestion:
=MAKEARRAY(ROWS(J2:J4),COLUMNS(K1:M1),LAMBDA(u,v,
SUM(IFERROR(BYROW(E2:E4,LAMBDA(q,FILTER(C2:C6,(A2:A6=q)* 
(B2:B6=INDEX(J2:J4,u))))),0)*CHOOSECOLS(F2:H4,v))))


